# Converting between bases in C++

Tags: josephus

A C++ program that converts and input number from base 2, 5,8 and 16 to base 10. I have tried solving the problem using switch case but the base of 16 is giving me problems.

Comment: We can't help if you don't show some code that duplicates the problem. Please edit your question and add this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this link will help you : 
www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/31776/